# Trying to add physics to leather strap on thors hammer

Tags: rigging, physics, constraints

I am attempting to add realistic physics to the leather strap on Thor's hammer. Photos for reference:

[image: photo 1]

[image: photo 2]

The strap is a bezier curve, with a soft body, and i am trying to constrain it to the bottom handle of the hammer. And as you can see i made a hole in the handle so i could actually fit the strap through, in case that helped with my physics. I tried using a point constraint and was messing around with some other physics tools, that i saw online, but i have not been able to achieve the goal i want, which is the strap to realistically hang from the handle. And more specifically, have one small section of the strap locked into place under that little handle object, and the other parts of the strap be able to stretch and fall. I want to be able to create an animation of the hammer swinging with the strap stretching, and other stuff like that.

If pictures aren't loading correctly try this google drive link [click here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1IZmSQFElH303EWtgBVFgwSfEh-gBbcyD0MvfMY8v1M8/edit?usp=sharing) (there's also a gif of what i want the hammer to be able to do with the strap -which is swing the hammer)

Also, researching online for this, the closest thing i could find to what i wanted is in this video if you care to take a look. [click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_Fy9DlFwsM) or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_Fy9DlFwsM

Comment: which photo reference?

Comment: can you not see the two photos i attached? This is my first question i've posted so I could've added them incorrectly, but i can see the photos on my computer.

Comment: As "reference photo" I expected a frame from a movie, something "real" you're  trying to reproduce. I only see two screenshot of what I guess is your currently model...

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain how to get the soft-body physics to work, because I myself still don't entire understand soft-body physics.

*However*, I can give an alternate way that I know works.

-Instead of using a curve, create a mesh that is just a single edge-loop, no thickness.

-Add cloth physics to it.

-Select the vertices of the area that is inside the hammer handle (going a couple vertices outside the volume of the handle mesh will help avoid collision glitches as well as add to the stiff look), and add them to a vertex group.

-Under the cloth physics, toggle on "Pinning", and select the vertex group you just made.

-In the modifiers tab, you'll see a cloth physics modifier.  **After** this modifier (that is, below it), add a solidify modifier; increase the thickness as appropriate.

-Add collision physics to the hammer mesh.

-Parent the strap mesh to the hammer mesh.

-I found that cranking up the "Bending" parameter under the cloth physics goes a long way in emulating the stiff, cord-like physics of the real strap in the movies.